# Laravel - Form validation error - argument 2 must be array

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I'm working with Laravel and every time I submit my form it gives me this error:

ErrorException in Factory.php line 91:
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php on line 83 and defined

This is some code for the controller, even when I don't try to send data to the database it gives me this error. (now it's just redirecting)

```
public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
{


    return Redirect::to('/index');

}
```

This is how I defined my routes:

```
Route::get('/projects','ProjectsController@index');
Route::get('/create','ProjectsController@create');

Route::post('/create','ProjectsController@store');
```

The line the error refers to is what is in the return section here:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $factory = $this->container->make('Illuminate\Validation\Factory');

    if (method_exists($this, 'validator')) {
        return $this->container->call([$this, 'validator'], compact('factory'));
    }

    return $factory->make(
        $this->all(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
    );
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You need to post the code for your `Validator::make()`. Make sure the first parameter is the input array eg: `$request->all()` and the second parameter is your rules array eg: `['email' => 'required|email'...]`

Comment: thank you for posting this question!!!

Comment: I had a partial installation of the framework which produced exactly this same error. I copied all the files across again (restoring missing files) and then the problem went away.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem is in your `StoreProjectRequest` and it's `rules()` method. It should return array and in your code it probably returns something else. Check it, please.

Comment: you saved my day Maxim. Newbie for laravel. Thanks a ton!!! By mistake i deleted return statement as it was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error for `Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\ModelManager::add(): Argument #2 ($attributes) must be of type array, null given`.
Used `WithValidation` class method `public function prepareForValidation($data, $index)`, but  made the mistake not adding `return $data` inside this method.